# what is 1-norm mean?

Tags: math, norm

When I reading paper, I found 1-norm or 2-norm. like this: [image]
However, I can not understand this word? Is it mean that the normal distribution with mean 1?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's obviously not a programming question.

Comment: OK, thank you @JamesKPolk, I will post similar statistics to Cross Validated. Best

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1-norm for a vector is sum of absolute values. 2-norm is the usual Euclidean norm - square root of the sum of the squares of the values

[image: 1-norm-defn]

[image: 2-norm-defn]

Comment: Thanks, In the context, the author say that "1-norm or 2-norm", it seems that these two norms are alternative and can be replaced with each other?

Comment: What the author (probably) means is that the problem formulation doesn't care whether you use the 1-norm or the 2-norm. You just replace p_1 and p_2 with either 1 or 2 as appropriate in every place that follows.

Comment: @Anderson thanks I also read the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)